# Make vpn between ubuntu server and my home pc

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vpn

I have one server which is located in different country and i never used to setup VPN before so i don't know much about it. Although i know about configuring web servers and game servers, and currently i have proxy setup on my server so i can connect from home and browse through proxy but i wanna go step further and setup vpn which will mask everything and show that im located where my server is, and that i can connect with anything, pidgin, skype, browsing, etc... but i don't know from where to start

My server is Ubuntu 12 32 bit and don't have installed any of web services (it's not used for anything except for learning and testing now) it only have desktop xfce and vnc so i can connect to it.

And my home pc have windows 7 64 bit

So where do i start. Open vpn maybe?

Comment: [This guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openvpn.html) should prove very helpful. Good luck.

Comment: Although it's good starting point i still didn't managed to connect, and all the explanations on net i found how to connect linux to linux vpn but my home pc is windows what to do now to connect windows to vpn server i just created.